# （Qt）How to output the content selected in combo box to TXT file?

Tags: c++, qt

I just started learning Qt, and I want to make a program that can output the input content to a txt file.I can just output the content in textEdit to txt file.But I don't know how to output the content selected in combo box or the content selected in radio button.

Widget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void pressBtn();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

Widget.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui- 
>pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(pressBtn()));
}

//output the content in textEdit

void Widget::pressBtn(){
    QString str=ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString str2=ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText();
    QString str3=str+str2;
    str3.replace("\n","\r\n");
    qDebug()<<str3;
    QFile file("C:/1.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("error"),tr("Fail to open 
    the file!"));
        return;
}
QTextStream in(&file);
in<<str3;
QMessageBox::information(this,tr("tips"),tr("success!"));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("C:/1.txt"));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->textEdit_2->clear();
    ui->textEdit->clear();
}
```

UI image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVDqY.png)

Comment: Show your code, then we can tell you what to do to make it work.

Comment: `QUrl("C:/1.txt")` that is not the URL you want. URLs for local files need a "file:" scheme. You want `QUrl("file:///C:/1.txt")`, or even better `QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/1.txt")`. You might also want to call `file.close()` explicitly before expecting content to be actually written to the file.

Comment: Side note: Using a variable named `QTextStream in` as an output stream is confusing to readers of your code. It looks like an input stream.

Comment: It looks like you already know how to write to a file generally since you say it's working for your TextEdit. So is the real problem that you don't know how to extract the strings out of your combobox?

Comment: That's just it.I want to know how to extract the selected one in the combo box.

Comment: Does `QComboBox::currentText()` help?